# App closes when iPhone screen is locked

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Whenever i have my app open, then lock my screen, the app closes if the screen is locked for more than 5 minutes. So when I unlock the phone again, I am at my home screen and have to re-open the app.

This happens on both iPhone 6 device and simulator. However, if I build and run the app using the debugger, it doesn't happen, which is making it difficult to fix.

I'd appreciate any suggestions that might point me in the right direction.

Comment: how did you run in simulator without debugger?

Comment: @HarikrishnanT Just run it with the debugger first, then stop from the debugger. Then go to your simulator and open the app.

Comment: This happens in most of apps running on my iPhone4S but not on my iPhone 6. This happens because of low memory. Try to debug your memory leaks and allocations. When user locks the screen(application goes to background mode), iOS automatically kill the app in low memory condition.